# Utility Types that extend other Interfaces

Tags: typescript

I know that I can use utility types in type script, e.g. [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys), to build other types. But let's say after I `Pick` some of the properties from an interface, I want that new type to extend another interface.

```
export interface ICreateRequestVo {
};


export interface IFoo {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
};

export type FooRequestVo = Pick<IFoo, 'foo'>;
```

Now when I try to make `FooRequestVo` extends `ICreateRequestVo`, I get the following error:

```
export type FooRequestVo = Pick<IFoo, 'foo'> extends ICreateRequestVo;

TS1005: '?' expected.
```

Comment: you cant extends interface but you can implmenets it

Comment: `ICreateRequestVo` is empty and therefore `FooRequestVo` automatically extends it.  Even for example code, [you shouldn't declare empty interfaces](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces).  Maybe you could update the example to show what you want?  Anyway you can either use an intersection type or you can create a new interface, like [this code shows](https://tsplay.dev/m35kkw).  Do either or both of those work for you?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a type intersection:

```ts
type FooRequestVo = Pick<IFoo, 'foo'> & ICreateRequestVo;
```

Regarding the error: TypeScript thinks you want to use a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) such as:

```ts
type TypeE = TypeA extends TypeB ? typeC : typeD
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know this thing exists